# Python 3.5.1 Cannot download Robot Framework library

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to automate a test with Robot Framework. When I tried downloading the library via `pip` I ran into some issues.
I'm using `Python 3.5.1`, `Robot Framework 3.0`, `PyCharm 2016.1(64)`,

Output for command `pip install robotframework-selenium2library`:

`Collecting robotframework-selenium2library
  Using cached robotframework-selenium2library-1.7.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Extracting in C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpooendh2g
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
        raise ImportError
    ImportError`

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gh4jw21a\robotframework-selenium2library\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
    _extractall(tar)
  File "c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ez_setup.py", line 467, in _extractall
    self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Radek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gh4jw21a\robotframework-selenium2library\

Setuptools are up-to-date, so is ez_setup

`C:\Users\Radek>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\Radek>pip install ez_setup
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ez-setup in c:\users\radek\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages`

Comment: can you download other libraries without issue?  How about trying an older version of setuptools/ez_setup?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium2Library is not (yet) compatible with Python 3.x.

We have a Pull Request (github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/pull/564) to have Selenium2Library compatible with all Python versions, but it is not in the official Release, and it was tested with Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.4.

I you want to install you could try github.com/HelioGuilherme66/robotframework-selenium2library/releases/tag/v1.8.0b1
For example with:
pip install -U --pre https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/robotframework-selenium2library/archive/v1.8.0b1.zip